# Test for posts matching specific category and not belonging to exclusion category

Tags: wordpress

I have a function below whose purpose is to create a listing of posts where the category assigned to each post is "top-menu". However, I first want to exclude any posts where the category is "hidden"...

How can I edit this code to do that?

```
global $post;
$cat = get_cat_ID('top-menu');
if ($cat > 1) 
  $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category='.$cat);
else
  $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=10');
foreach ($myposts as $post) :
?> 
<li>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: reformat first - this makes my brain hurt

Comment: Hey @Scott B, you need to indent each line 4 spaces or more for large blocks of code. Using the backtick is just for single or a short phrases of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want. Not sure why you had the `if` statement, so feel free to incorporate again if you need it. You can always just use `category` and give it an id instead of `category_name` as I am using here as a shortcut.

```
$exclude_cat = get_cat_ID('hidden');
$include_cat = get_cat_ID('top-menu');

$myposts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts'      => 5,
    'category__in'     => array( $include_cat ),
    'category__not_in' => array( $exclude_cat )
));
```

**EDIT:** `category_name` cannot be combined with `category__not_in`, so I changed the code slightly so both filters would be run.

I have tested this and it works in WordPress 2.8, just be sure to supply the actual category name in the `get_cat_ID` calls and not the `slug` by accident.

Comment: Don't believe you can combine category parameters like that. Could use 'category__in' with an array of category ids that does NOT contain the hidden category.

Comment: You were half right :) You cannot combine `category_name` and `category__not_in` but you can combine `category__in` and `category__not_in` with great success. Thanks for pointing the problem out. I have fixed my code example and tested that it works.

Comment: Oops, have to correct that statement. category__not_in doesn't work with category_name, but category__not_in works with the 'cat' => 4 argument (where 4 is the category id)

Comment: Nice to know you can use plain 'ol `cat` as well. Thanks for testing!

Answer (score 1):

Noting that dcneiner's revised suggestion works.  That query generates this SQL

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
  ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
  ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)  
WHERE 1=1  
  AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'  
  AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN ('3')  
  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN 
  ( SELECT tr.object_id FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr 
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt 
      ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
    WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category' 
    AND tt.term_id IN ('1') ) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
  OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```